# using grep or awk to search and print the text into a file

Tags: linux

I have 500 outfiles, where in i want to print the ENERGY VALUES(text made in bold). Please have a glance of a single out file

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------   
FINAL RESULTS
 ENERGY    -1.5576E+03   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Requesting you the help me with a linux command to print all the energy values according to the outfiles generated and save it on to a new file "say" list.nomenclature of my outfiles are output1.out, output1.out,output3.out and so on!

Comment: please try some tutorials please or add the code you have already tried !

Comment: i did tried cat *.out  | grep '"ENERGY"{print $2 $3}' >list , it did provided the output filename but didnt provided me the energy value i.e -1.5576E+03

Answer (score 0):

This *may* be as simple as simply doing:

```
grep ENERGY output*.out /dev/null
```

It simply outputs all lines containing the `ENERGY` string from all specified input files, in the form:

```
output1.out:ENERGY 3.21 gigawatts
output2.out:ENERGY 3.141492653589 km.V/s^2
output3.out:ENERGY (hardly any)
```

(not real units, obviously).

The `/dev/null` trick is simply to ensure file name is still listed if there's only one. The behaviour of `grep` in that case is to just print the line *without* the file name, so adding another input file ensures files are always shown.

Comment: the output is below mentioned, meanwhile i am not geting the energy values i.e-1.5576E+03   
output100.out:     ENERGY        
-----------------------------

Answer (score 0):

You could have use `awk`:

```
for f in output*.out
do
    # print the filename without a newline
    echo -n $f >> nomenclature.list
    # tells awk to search for the line containing ENERGY,
    # then print the last field of the line (whitespaces as default field
    # separator)
    awk '/ENERGY/ { print $NF; }' $f >> nomenclature.list
done
```